# I just wrote a random number generator in PHP how do you think this can be improved?

Tags: php, performance, processing-efficiency, memory-efficient

I was working for a client and he wanted codes generated in the format [char][int][int] like in T56, N78, J89, etc... The char has to be in upper case.

As a quickie I wrote this function as I found it the simplest

```
function randomizer(){
    $chars = array("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z");
    return $chars[array_rand($chars)].mt_rand(10, 99);
}
```

But I kept on wondering that there will be many other efficient solutions. This one above just works, but I am looking more towards efficiency as I need to generate loads of such Codes.

What better place to start!

Comment: **static** `$chars = range('A', 'Z');`

Comment: Are values like 'T05' allowed?  your function does not generate them.

Comment: That's not a random number generator. You're **USING** a random number generator.

Comment: @Wug indeed they are allowed and my code is wrong, my bad!

Comment: @MarcB my bad again! it should be a random code generator
I think the solution i selected is working a bit better...

Comment: @wrongnumber Unique in what scope? Unique to the current execution of the script, or unique across multiple calls? If unique across multiple calls, how will you keep track of codes that have been used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo chr(mt_rand(65,90)).str_pad((rand()%100),2,0,STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

Comment: really nice... my code had errors as mentioned it was not generating codes like T07...

Answer (score 0):

You'd want to store `$chars` outside of the function if you can, so it doesn't need to be created every time (if you wanted to generate 1000 codes in a loop for example).

Also, here is a shortcut for you

`$chars = range("A","Z");`

Answer (score 0):

```
function getRandStr()
{
    return sprintf("%s%02d", chr(mt_rand(65, 90)), mt_rand(0, 99));
}
```

**EDIT:** Changed according to comment, thanks @DaveRandom.

Comment: I think you forgot to `chr()` the first part afterwards, and since `ord('A')` and `ord('Z')` never change it would be better to hard code the integers. Plus I think `sprintf('%02s', mt_rand(0, 99))` would be more efficient for the second part